# How to create grid lines on top of an image in css?

Tags: html, css, grid, background-image, linear-gradients

I have noticed that you can create grid-lines by using, for example:

```
background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(0deg,transparent,#CCC 0,transparent 3px,transparent 10%), repeating-linear-gradient(-90deg,transparent,#CCC 0,transparent 3px,transparent 10%);}
```

So, my question is how can you create grid-lines that will go on top of an background image while not using the above?

Comment: Add the gradient to another element positioned over the image? Or use photoshop

Comment: Or add it to a `pseudo-element`.

Comment: use multiple image with gradient first to stick on top : `background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(0deg,transparent,#CCC 0,transparent 3px,transparent 10%), repeating-linear-gradient(-90deg,transparent,#CCC 0,transparent 3px,transparent 10%), url(my_img_under_grid_lines.jpg);}`

Comment: @GCyrillus, but what about when the user sends his own background-image? Which is what is happening in my case.

Comment: You could instead lay over it a pseudo : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oeXOmN

Comment: @GCyrillus, thank you for this , it solved my problem with some adjustments.

Answer (score 1):

You could use data URLs! https://codepen.io/tutorialsetc/pen/IEuFq

Here's a sample of html:

```
<div class="patterns">
<p class="pattern09"></p>
</div>
```

And CSS with data url:

```
.pattern09{
background-image:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAAECAQAAADl0Z2xAAAAEElEQVQIHWNgYGD4b8UABgAJmgE6cUJg+wAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==);
}
```

There are lots of data url generators out there. Then just overlay it over your image.